# Multiple selects with the same options

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

[image: Mockup]

I need to create multiple select with the same set of options, as illustrated in the mockup above. Selected options need to be removed from all the other selects, as shown in the picture. How do I achieve this in Angular? Here is a snippet of what I have written.

```
<div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
  <div *ngFor="let index of [0, 1, 2, 3]" class="card mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">
      Destination {{ index + 1 }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPlanets[index]">
          <option *ngFor="let planet of planets" [value]="planet.name">
            {{planet.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using a pipe to filter out the selected options, but it does not recognize changes. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can push the previous selected values into an separated array and then you can achieve what you want with `*ngIf` like `selectedPlanets.find(item => item.name !== planet.name)`. This will ensure that it will render only if the item don't exists in the selectedPlanets array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a method on your component that is called on the array in the *ngFor expression.  This method can filter out selections that have already been made in previous choices to a certain index.

**Component method**

```
filterChoices(choices: [], selections: [], maxIndex) {
  const inBoundsSelections = selections.filter((x, i) => i <= maxIndex);
  return choices.filter(x => inBoundsSelections.indexOf(x) === -1);
}
```

**Template**

```
<option 
   *ngFor="let planet of filterChoices(planets, selectedPlanets, index - 1)"
   [value]="planet.name">
  {{planet.name}}
</option>
```

Comment: For performance reasons you should consider using pipes as suggested in my answer. Pipes provide a memoization, which does not let the pipe recalculate everything on each change. This maybe doesn't matter if you have got just a very few items. But if it get's a little larger you should really consider using pipes. Check out this demonstration on [ngConf2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ZvpdRM1eQ).

Comment: Is the pipe transform function called whenever the data has changed?

Comment: @ngfelixl - Thanks for the link as I didn't know about that benefit of Pipes.  However, in both our examples we pass an array as an additional parameter which I think will either negate the benefits of the pipe or worse yet malfunction because the pipe will not get the update.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write a filtering pipe for your purpose.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'remove'})
export class RemovePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(options: string[], toRemove: string[]): string[] {
    return options.filter(option => !toRemove.includes(option));
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
<select #name1>
  <option [value]="planet.name" *ngFor="let planet of planets"></option>
</select>
<select #name2>
  <option [value]="planet.name" *ngFor="let planet of planets | remove:[name1.value]"></option>
</select>
<select #name3>
  <option [value]="planet.name" *ngFor="let planet of planets | remove:[name1.value, name2.value]"></option>
</select>
```

If you want to use a dynamic number of selects, try using Reactive Forms as they provide the very handy FormArray.

Edit for completeness: In the corresponding module you have to declare the pipe

```
import { RemovePipe } from 'pathto/remove.pipe'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ RemovePipe ]
})
```